# Mongodb group by consults in colab

Tags: mongodb, group

I have to make a consult on a data base in Mongodb, but usin colab (google colab), i found that the existing documentation (oficial and every other site) have a similar way of doing the consult but not de same (in colab with "less tan" operator yo have to do "$lt" and $lt doesn't work) thas why i am here asking how can i translate a group by and sum consult.

For more detail i want to group by name of publisher and sum another field (weeks on best seller)

```
Query = collection.aggregate(
    [
      {'$group':{'_id': 'publisher', 'Cantidad_total': { "$sum": 'weeks_on_list' }}}])

for elemento in Query:
  pprint.pprint(elemento)
```

this is what i came up with (that doesn´t fail) but give this

```
{'Cantidad_total': 0, '_id': 'publisher'}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample document from the database

Comment: Without seeing your documents It's difficult to know for sure, but does this get you closer to what you are looking for? `{'$group':{'_id': '$publisher', 'Cantidad_total': { "$sum": '$weeks_on_list' }}}`?  Note the placements of `$`.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much, if you make it an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a couple of `$`.

From the docs:

> [Expressions:](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions)
>
> Expressions can include  field paths ,  literals ,  system variables ,
> expression objects , and  expression operators . Expressions can be
> nested.
>
> Field Paths:
>
> Aggregation expressions use field path to access fields in the input
> documents. To specify a field path, prefix the field name or the
> dotted field name (if the field is in the embedded document) with a
> dollar sign $. For example, "$user" to specify the field path for the
> user field or "$user.name" to specify the field path to "user.name"
> field.

So for your particular example, you want your aggregation pipeline to be:

```json
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$publisher",
      "Cantidad_total": {
        "$sum": "$weeks_on_list"
      }
    }
  }
]
```